# How to compute for "Engaged Time" in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a set of data like this:

```
       |      A         |          B       | 
       -------------------------------------
    1  | Start Time     |   End  Time      |
    2  |  6:43 AM       |     7:00 AM      |
    3  |  8:01 AM       |     9:43 AM      |
    4  |  8:02 AM       |     8:20 AM      |
    5  |  8:22 AM       |     8:57 AM      |
    6  |  8:58 AM       |     9:55 AM      |
    7  |  1:20 PM       |     2:41 PM      |
    8  |  1:27 PM       |     2:11 PM      |
```

Each row represents instances that an employee is working on a task, in this case, within 6:43 AM to 2:11 PM. So using common sense, you would deduct the 'End Time' to the 'Start Time' to get the length of 'Engaged' time. But that's not the Engaged time. That's the 'Task Length'. The length of time he took to finish 1 task.

The issue here is 1 employee can work on multiple tasks at the same time. If you look at row 3 (8:01AM to 9:43AM), the employee took more than 1 hour to complete 1 task. While doing that specific task, he started doing other tasks in rows 4 5 and 6.

so thinking about 'Engaged Time' he was engaged from 8:01AM until 9:55AM. I cannot think of a dynamic formula that will do this automatically for the entire table. Another issue is that, this is a data set for just 1 employee for 1 day. I have 10 employees that work 5 days a week. They produce roughly 3,000 rows of data in 1 month. Can you suggest a formula, pivot table technique, or VBA code for me to crunch the numbers dynamically?

Thank you!

Comment: not sure I understand the entire problem or question. Part of it may be helped if there was a 3rd area called open time. For example in the table it appears there was opening from 7:01 AM to 8:00 AM.  Would that help if it existed?

Comment: Yes! I was thinking about that too. That is actually called the "Non-Engaged Time". There's another technique that I can think of that will sum up all the "Time logged"  (A1 - B8) then deduct the "Non-Engaged Time". The result from that will be exactly what I need. However, due to the data being very dynamic. I can't think of a formula for it. The fact that employees can do several tasks at the same time and the "end time" can be very dynamic, limits me from finding that open time.

Comment: How are these times generated? I can turn on the TV and not be engaged in it. I can start the oven and put a turkey in the oven and not be engaged on the turkey for 2 hours. What are you trying to capture? Productivity? I worked for a company once and the boss told me that my 10 key was too slow that day. That was my last day, I quit.

Comment: Ah, this is auto generated in the system. Each line item is actually an interaction with a customer in a chat system. so 1 employee can chat several customers at the same time. I didn't detail the specifics in my post above as I wanted to be as general as possible. But to answer your question, yes Productivity. I need to see it to know if I need to hire more people. But that's a different discussion and I don't want to derail my original question.

Comment: what is your desired output? For your sample data just one number summing all engaged time? For your real data do you also have separate column where you keep employee and date?

Comment: If I understand the question, your definition of "engaged time" doesn't care whether the employee is doing multiple tasks.  So why doesn't daily end time minus daily start time work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps,  make 2 helper columns, the first one is block number. This shows a block of time that there is one or more tasks going.  [image]

The formulas are e3=1, f3=c3 to provide a starting point start.

The rest of the e column starting with e4 uses

- =+IF(B4>F3,1,0)+E3

where it is checking the new start time to see if it is inside of the current end time. if is, the block is extended, else a new block number is started

The f column starting with f4 uses

- =+IF(E4>E3,C4,MAX(C4,F3))

Where is checking to see if the block end time has been extended. For each block, the min time in b and the max in c will generate the engaged time.

I hope I understand your problem enough.

Comment: This is the answer! I just needed to add a couple of columns to check the MIN of the block and the Max of the block then I deduct those two to get the "Engaged Time". Thank you very much!